# The Type or namespace name "WinContols" does not exist in the namespace 'Telerik'

Tags: webforms, visual-studio-2017, telerik, telerik-mvc

I picked up an Desktop Application written in ASP .NET Web Forms that has been developer 5 years ago and the person is not around. I do need to make some changes but I am stuck and getting it running. (I am using VS17)

I google the issue but unfortunately there is so little out there about it and most of them are really old.

I am missing come Telerik References. To be exact here are list of them.
[image]

I have tried  [this one](https://www.telerik.com/forums/visual-studio-2017-missing-telerik-extension-menu-item) but was not successful. I followed the steps here but got stock at adding

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders\Telerik UI for WinForms Q1 2014]@="C:\Program Files\Telerik\UI for WinForms\Q1 2014\bin\"

My Telerik looks to be installed at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Progress\Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX R1 2019

I do not have a bin folder. 
[image]

And if I go to those bin folders I don't have anything like Telerik.WinControls.****

I am not sure if it is still supported or what I am doing wrong. I have got bunch of other errors but I have a feeling that they are all related to these missing namespaces.
[image]

Any help would be much apricated.

**EDIT**

Based on first comment, I was able to fix that issue. Thanks for that!

I have got this error now. Not quiet clear to me how to approach this. Any thoughts?
[image]

Comment: The missing assemblies are part of the [Telerik WinForms](https://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx) product, which is different to the UI for ASP.NET AJAX. Looks like you need to download and install it too.

Comment: Helpful! do you have any thoughts on error I added to the question?

Comment: Basically it's saying that Telerik.WinControls.UI uses version 2019.1.219.40 of Telerik.WinControls, but the version of Telerik.WinContols that you've got referenced in the project is a lower version: 2019.1.219.20.